# Split a list into a subset of lists which do not share values in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of non-unique values that is quite long.

I want to split this vector into four about equally long vectors, where no two vectors can contain the same value, but each of the four vectors may contain 1 or more different values.

Example:

```
List <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,5,5,5,5,9,11,11)
```

list1 = 1,1,1
list2 = 2,3,3
list3 = 5,5,5,5
list4 = 9,11,11

What is the best way to implement this in R?

Comment: What do you want to split the list based on?  Sequence?  If so try `rle()`.  What criteria are you using to determine what goes in which sub-list (e.g. when can a sub-list have more than one value)?

Comment: A sublist can have more than one value because there may be 8 values but 4 sublists. Each value must belong to only one sublist.

Comment: Could you talk to us a bit about your purpose? ie, what are you planning to do with the vectors after you've broken them into 4? Are they categorical variables or continuous variables?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create exactly four sub-lists, of approximately equal length?  So your optimization could shift elements around until you wind up with sub-lists of as equal a length as possible?  How many potential elements do you have?  How big is the list?  Does order matter?  How optimum does it have to be?  How fast does it have to run?

Comment: Here is exactly what I want to do: I have a data frame and I want to group it by one of the non-unique values and split the data frame into four separate dataframes. But that non-unique value cannot repeat across dataframes.

Comment: How equal in size do the resulting data frames have to be?  That's the hard part, and is what makes the answers so far complex.

Comment: The equal in size part is not the important part.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :

Based on the comments after the original question, you can simply do :

```
my.sample <- function(x,n){

  samples <- rle(List)$lengths
  ng <- length(samples)
  groups <- cut(1:ng,n,labels=FALSE)
  reps <- tapply(samples,groups,sum)
  rep(1:n,reps)

}
> my.sample(List,4)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

to get a vector you can use in `split()`.

---

Problems arise if you start having vectors like c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4). If you don't mind the order to be shifted, you can construct a function for that, based on following logic :

- split the vector in a list of vectors of unique values
- combine them into n groups
- go over n groups and check whether they're all of -more or less- equal length. If not, switch one value from the largest one to the smallest one.
- proceed until the difference is less than the modulus of the total length and the number of groups, or you ran the algorithm say 10 times (in some extreme cases you could end up with an infinite while loop)

This gives following function

```
my.sample <- function(x,n){
  # these are the unique values from which to sample
  samples <- split(x,x)
  ns <- length(samples)

  groups <- list()
  # make sure that sample() returns n groups
  while(length(groups)!=n){
    groups <- split(samples,sample(1:n,ns,replace =TRUE))
  }

  count <- 0
  lgroups <- c(1,ns)

  while(diff(range(lgroups)) > ns%%n & count < 10 ){

    lgroups <- sapply(groups,function(i)length(unlist(i))) # length of groups
    ngroups <- sapply(groups,length) # number of unique values
    id <- which(ngroups > 1) # which groups have more than one unique value

    #switch one value from the largest to the smallest group
    gmin <- which.min(lgroups)
    gmax <- id[which.max(lgroups[id])]
    gsw <- sample(1:length(groups[gmax]),1)
    groups[[gmin]] <- c(groups[[gmin]],groups[[gmax]][gsw])
    groups[[gmax]] <- groups[[gmax]][-gsw]
    count <- count+1
  }
  # create the output
  lapply(groups,unlist,use.names=FALSE)  

}
```

It can be applied as such :

```
> my.sample(List,4)
$`1`
[1] 5 5 5 5

$`2`
[1] 11 11  2

$`3`
[1] 3 3 9

$`4`
[1] 1 1 1
```

It can still be finetuned to your own need, but this seems an R-like way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very mediocre algorithm that comes close to what it sounds like you might want.

```
n.groups <- 4
L <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,5,5,5,5,9,11,11)
N <- length(L)

L <- sort(L)
L.rle <- rle(L)

ave.grp.length <- N/n.groups

lgths <- L.rle$lengths
vals <- L.rle$values

res <- list(one=c(),two=c(),three=c(),four=c())
l <- 1
for(i in seq(length(vals)) ) {
  if( sum(res[[l]])>=ave.grp.length & l<n.groups ) {
    l <- l+1
  }
  res[[l]] <- c( res[[l]], rep(vals[i],lgths[i]) )
}
```

Ways in which it could be improved:

- You may prefer your output in condensed form since you say your list is quite big.  That may save you some serious compute time, since replicating the condensed data is inefficient.
- It currently works in sequential order.  This is both easier and faster computationally.  If you really want to coerce groups to be as similarly-sized as possible, you can mess around with other algorithms, or add a second pass to go back through at the end and even them out.
- It's loop-based, which is rarely the best way to do things in R.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to gsk3's solution in that it uses `rle` but instead tries to find the closest split to the desired quantile.  (It may suffer from an off by one error; I suspect I'm not comparing the quantile and the result from `rle` quite correctly.)

```
mysplit <- function(List, n) {
  q <- length(List)*(1:(n-1))/n
  d <- cumsum(rle(List)$lengths)
  x <- d[apply(abs(outer(q, d, `-`)),1,which.min)]
  x <- c(0,x,length(List))
  lapply(1:n, function(i) List[(x[i]+1):x[i+1]])
}
```

With an output of:

```
> List <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,5,5,5,5,9,11,11)
> mysplit(List, 4)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 3

[[3]]
[1] 5 5 5 5

[[4]]
[1]  9 11 11
```

Also note that it only works if there are enough unique identifiers so that the groups have positive length; in particular it doesn't work for Joris's example.

Here's a simpler way if equal length isn't important; it just fills the four groups in order, one unique value at a time.

```
mysplit2 <- function(List, n) {
  spl <- split(List, List)
  lapply(0:(n-1), function(x) unname(unlist(spl[(seq_along(spl)-1) %% n == x])))
}
```

It's probably slow but it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

An approach which tries to pack the groups fairly close to "full", by pairing off the values with the most and least repetitions. Far from optimal in terms of packing, but fairly quick. Returns a vector so that you can split the entire data.frame into batches easily.

```
bucket = function(x, n) {
  x = factor(x)
  l = table(x)
  g = as.list(names(l[l >= n]))
  l = sort(rev(l[l < n]))
  while (length(l)) {
    big = names(which(cumsum(rev(l)) <= n))
    left = n - sum(l[big])
    l = l[seq_len(length(l) - length(big))]
    small = names(which(cumsum(l) <= left))
    l = l[seq_len(length(l) - length(small)) + length(small)]
    g = c(g, list(c(small, big)))
  }
  unname(setNames(rep(seq_along(g), sapply(g, length)), unlist(g))[levels(x)][x])
}

x = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,5,5,5,5,9,11,11)
n = 4

split(x, bucket(x, 4))
```